# WooCommerce - Change price display in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

First, thanks for your time.

We have certain products we offer a payment plan with, and it includes a $1 30day trial.

When a user adds a product to the cart with the "payment plan" category (`id=41` below), I want the cart to display the price as $1 then X payments of `$xx.xx`. The back end only needs to pass the product SKU so this is purely for display reasons.

This code works, but loops for however many items are in the cart. Is there a way for me to stop the loop as soon as it senses the "payment plan" product category?

The Code:

```
        <td><?php 
                    function check_payment() {
                    //Check to see if user has product in cart
                    global $woocommerce;

                    //assigns a default negative value

                    $contains_special = false;

                    $wccart= WC()->cart->get_cart();

                    if ( !empty( $wccart ) ) {
                        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

                            function is_item_special( $product_id ){
                                if( has_term( 'payment-plan', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                                    return TRUE;
                                } else {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }//function

                            if ( is_item_special( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {

                                    $contains_special = true;
                                    $firstpayment = get_post_meta( $_product->id, 'firstpayment', true );
                                    $getsubtotal = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); //get cart subtotal
                                    $trimbefore = str_replace('<span class="amount">&#36;', "", $getsubtotal); //$getsubtotal returns <span class="amount>XX.XX</span> this trims off the opening span tag
                                    $intsubtotal = str_replace('</span>', "", $trimbefore); //trim closing span tag
                                    $formatsubtotal = number_format((float)$intsubtotal, 2, '.', '');//makes an integer

                                    $numberofpayments = get_post_meta( $_product->id, 'payments', true );

                                    $afterfirsttotal = $formatsubtotal - 1.00;
                                    $paymentamount = number_format((float)$afterfirsttotal, 2, '.', '') / $numberofpayments;


                                    echo '$' . $firstpayment . '<br/> then ' . $numberofpayments . ' payments of $' . number_format((float)$paymentamount, 2, '.', '');
                                    break;
                                } else {
                                wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html();
                                }//if/else statement
                        }//foreach loop
                    } //if cart isn't empty
                    } //function
```

?>

I'm semi-new to PHP and still trying to understand some things, so sorry if this is just obvious!

Comment: I'm not trying to be an ass, but have you tried researching what those error messages mean? What do you not understand about what you've found?That way we can help you with more specific information.

Comment: Hey @helgatheviking I have researched a little. I guess more of what I'm asking is is there a way to just see if a product category is in the cart, doesn't matter which item, as long as the category exists.

Comment: Ok, now you're asking a more SO-friendly question. Please see my answer.

Comment: PS- You may want to consider WooCommerce Subscriptions for this.

Comment: We started with Woocommerce Subscriptions, but it applies tax weirdly for how we need it to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that I have used in the past (slightly modified from when I was checking for a product with a particular post meta field). From what I can tell from your question, it seems that you are looking for `break` which is how to quit a foreach loop once a particular condition has been satisfied.

The first function loops through the cart items looking for any item that matches our criteria. Note the `if ( ! empty( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) )` which prevents the code from running on an empty cart.... which was the cause of the `foreach` error you were seeing earlier.

The second function checks a product for a particular condition: in your case whether or not it has a specific product category assigned. This could easily be handled inside the first function, but I refactored it out for readability.

```
/*
 * loop through cart looking for specific item
 */
function kia_check_cart_for_specials() {

        $contains_special = false;

        if ( ! empty( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                if ( kia_is_item_special( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
                    $contains_special = true;
                    break; // found a special item so we can quit now
                }
            }
        }

        return $contains_special;
}

/*
 * check if an item has special category
 * change the term/condition to suit your needs
 */
function kia_is_item_special( $product_id ){
    if( has_term( 'special-category', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```